# How to get results that begin with a number with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a table with a Name field containing data similar to the following:

a1
a2
b1
c1
1a
1b
2a
9b

I'm trying to select only the rows values that start with a number.

I'm trying to do this with the following query, but it doesn't work:

```
var numberGroups = _session
    .CreateCriteria<CompanyGroupInfo>()
    .Add(SqlExpression.Between<CompanyGroupInfo>(g => int.Parse(g.Name.Substring(0, 1)), 0, 9))
    .List<CompanyGroupInfo>();
```

It's throwing the error:

`Unrecognised method call in epression Parse(g.Name.Substring(0, 1))` note the 'expression' typo - that's NHibernate, not me :-)

Can somebody suggest how I can achieve the result I'm looking for? Thanks

**edit:** I tried Jon's suggestions below, as well as `SqlExpression.Not<CompanyGroupInfo>(g => !char.IsLetter(g.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToCharArray()[0]))` but they all throw similar errors to what I've posted above.

Comment: Similar, or exactly the same?

Comment: Similar, in that instead of  `Unrecognised method call in epression Parse(g.Name.Substring(0, 1))`, it would be  `Unrecognised method call in epression g.Name.get_Chars(0)` or  `Unrecognised method call in epression IsLetter(g.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToCharArray()[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, this is a better fit for HQL than Criteria.

A variation on Jamie's answer:

```
_session.CreateQuery(
        "from CompanyGroupInfo where substring(Name, 1, 1) between '0' and '9'")
        .List<CompanyGroupInfo>();
```

Anyway, if you really, really want to use Criteria... here it goes:

```
_session.CreateCriteria<CompanyGroupInfo>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Between(
             Projections.SqlFunction("substring",
                                     NHibernateUtil.String,
                                     Projections.Property("Name"),
                                     Projections.Constant(1),
                                     Projections.Constant(1)),
             "0", "9"))
        .List<CompanyGroupInfo>();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Could you comment on the efficiency of this compared to the solution I came up with below?

Comment: Well, of course this is much more efficient because all the filtering is done in the server. And, if you have an index on *Name*, it's done with an index scan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an NHibernate guru by any means, but have you tried:

```
SqlExpression.Between<CompanyGroupInfo>(g => g.Name.Substring(0, 1), "0", "9")
```

or

```
SqlExpression.Between<CompanyGroupInfo>(g => g.Name[0], '0', '9')
```

?

Comment: yeah, I tried those to no avail, as well as `SqlExpression.Not<CompanyGroupInfo>(g => !char.IsLetter(g.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToCharArray()[0]))`.. I think I must be coming at this from the wrong angle. It'd probably be easier for me to get the complete result set into a List, and filter it with good ol' linq-to-objects

Comment: @DaveDev: Please list what you've tried in the question, and what the result was. Then we may be able to help tune a suggestion or at least avoid the same suggestions.

Comment: don't get me wrong - I tried those after you suggested them. But yeah, I'll update the question with these. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this works:

```
var numberGroups = _session
    .CreateCriteria<CompanyGroupInfo>()
    .Add(SqlExpression.Not<CompanyGroupInfo>(/* where other criteria doesn't apply*/)
    .List<CompanyGroupInfo>()
    .Where(xx => char.IsDigit(xx.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToCharArray()[0]));
```

But I'm afraid it might be inefficient because I get the full result set into a list, and then filter the list. I'm open to other suggestions, if they're available.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get away with a naive solution?

```
_session.CreateQuery("from CompanyGroupInfo where Name < 'a'")
    .List<CompanyGroupInfo>();
```

The results depend on the database collation order and the Name data containing only letters and numbers.